# Rxjs: updating values in observable stream with data from another observable, returning a single observable stream

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

### Background

I'm trying to construct an observable stream of values from the [Stash Rest Api](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.11.3/stash-rest.html) of pull requests. Unfortunately, the information of whether or not a PR has merge conflicts is available at a different endpoint to the list of merges.

The list of open pull requests is visible at, say, http://my.stash.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/myproject/repos/myrepo/pull-requests

For each PR, the data on merge conflicts is visible at http://my.stash.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/myproject/repos/myrepo/pull-requests/[PR-ID]/merge

Using the [atlas-stash](https://github.com/dancrumb/atlas-stash) package, I can create and subscribe to an observable stream of pull requests (updated every second):

```
let pullRequestsObs = Rx.Observable.create(function(o) {
    stash.pullRequests(project, repo)
        .on('error', function(error) {o.onError(error)})
        .on('allPages', function(data) {
            o.onNext(data);
            o.onCompleted();
        });
    });

let pullRequestStream = pullRequestsObs
    .take(1)
    .merge(
        Rx.Observable
            .interval(1000)
            .flatMapLatest(pullRequestsObs)
    );

pullRequestsStream.subscribe(
    (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        // do something with data
    },
    (error) => log.error(error),
    () => log.info('done')
);
```

This works as I want and expect. In the end, the `pullRequestsStream` is an observable whose values are lists of JSON objects.

### My Goal

I would like the `pullRequestsStream` values to be updated so every element of the list includes information from the `[PR-ID]/merge` api.

I assume that this can be achieved using a `map` on `pullRequestsStream`, but I'm not succeeding in doing this.

```
let pullRequestWithMergeStream = pullRequestStream.map(function(prlist) {
    _.map(prlist, function(pr) {
        let mergeObs = Rx.Observable.create(function(o) {
            stash.pullRequestMerge(project, repo, pr['id'])
                .on('error', function(error) {o.onError(error)})
                .on('newPage', function(data) {
                    o.onNext(data);
                    o.onCompleted();
                }).take(1);
        });

        mergeObs.subscribe(
            (data) => {
                pr['merge'] = data;
                return pr; // this definitely isn't right
            },
            (error) => log.error(error),
            () => log.info('done')
        );
    });
});
```

With a bit of logging, I can see that both the pull-request and the merge apis are being hit correctly, but when I subscribe to `pullRequestWithMergeStream` I 
get undefined values.

Using `return` within the the `subscribe` step within a `map` doesn't work (and doesn't seem like it should) but I can't figure out what pattern/idiom would achieve what I want.

Is there a correct way of doing this? Have I gone completely down the wrong track?

### tl;dr

Can I update values from an Rxjs.Observable with information from *a different observable*?

Comment: A quick note for anyone who tries to do something similar: user3743222's answer below does what I asked, but now that I see it at work I see that I was trying to do a bad thing anyway. This creates a big bottleneck as dozens of observables are created at once and all poll the Stash REST API at once. This hoses the Stash server pretty badly. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: I updated the code to limit the number of simultaneous calls. No need to redraw :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `flatMap` or `concatMap` to have one task trigger another one. You could use `forkJoin` to request the merges in parallel and collect the result in one place. It is not tested, but it should go like this :

```
pullRequestStream.concatMap(function (prlist){
  var arrayRequestMerge = prlist.map(function(pr){
    return Rx.Observable.create(function(o) {...same as your code});
  });
  return Rx.Observable.forkJoin(arrayRequestMerge)
         .do(function(arrayData){
               prlist.map(function(pr, index){pr['merge']=arrayData[index]
             })})
         .map(function(){return prlist})
})
```

PS : I supposed `prlist` was an array.

**UPDATE** 
Following your comment, here is a version that will run only `maxConcurrent` calls in parallels.

```
pullRequestStream.concatMap(function (prlist){
  var arrayRequestMerge = prlist.map(function(pr, index){
    return Rx.Observable.create(function(o) {
        stash.pullRequestMerge(project, repo, pr['id'])
            .on('error', function(error) {o.onError(error)})
            .on('newPage', function(data) {
                o.onNext({data: data, index : index});
                o.onCompleted();
            }).take(1);
    });
  });
  var maxConcurrent = 2;
  Rx.Observable.from(arrayRequestMerge)
    .merge(maxConcurrent)
    .do(function(obj){
               prlist[obj.index]['merge'] = obj.data
             })})
    .map(function(){return prlist})
})
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much. I had been trying with `flatMap` but it didn't seem to be working for me. I wasn't aware of `concatMap` or `forkJoin`. The code given works out of the box, too.